# When changing into Rails folder, have rvm pick ruby and gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

For my different Rails folders, I would like to have rvm automatically load the correct gemset when running anything from 'bundle install' to doing my 'autotest' or rails console or server.  Is this possible?  Currently I have to manually do 'rvm use' which is getting a bit tedious as I am working on multiple Rails projects at the same time.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Create a `.rvmrc` file in your rails directory, and rvm will automatically load it. An example `.rvmrc` that loads Ruby 1.9.2 and a gemset named "rails3":

.rvmrc

```
rvm 1.9.2@rails3
```

You can do a lot more too, described in detail here: https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/

Answer (score 33):

For current versions of RVM, using two files is best practice:

```
.ruby-version
.ruby-gemset
```

http://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Comment: This is correct, the idea being that the .rvmrc file was RVM-specific whereas these files are version-manager agnostic.  I am not sure if chruby / rbenv support both of these yet or not though.

Answer (score 7):

For current RVM version 1.29.1, the recommended way is

```
rvm --ruby-version use <ruby-version>@<gemset>
```

Exmaple

```
rvm --ruby-version use 2.4.0@rails5
cat .ruby-version  # 2.4.0
cat ruby-gemset # rails5
```

this will generate two file `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-version` in your porject directory. This will compatible with other Ruby Versions Managers

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this in Gemfile

```
ruby '2.2.0'
ruby-gemset=significa
```

This way rvm will automatically pick the configured version

Answer (score 5):

Yaw just create two plain-text files and put into your project folder: 
**.ruby-gemset** and **.ruby-version**

**.ruby-gemset** should contain only gemset alias name and nothing else

**.ruby-version** follows the same rules, put your ruby version or alias there

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that by placing [an .rvmrc file](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/) at the base of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But, I found I had installed a ruby version globally while installing rvm.

I uninstalled that global version and everything started to work fine with **.ruby-version** and **.ruby-gemset** file in project's root directory.