# When changing folder rvm doesn't pick the correct ruby and gemset version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I work on multiple rails project and everytime I switch to some rails application I need to set ruby and gemset version. I tried setting it by default but it doesn't work correctly for other projects. I also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363502/when-changing-into-rails-folder-have-rvm-pick-ruby-and-gemset) which has given suggestion to create the below files but no luck.

```
.ruby-version
.ruby-gemset
```

Also, whenever I switch to a new tab in terminal again I need to set ruby and gemset version. I am not sure how to resolve it any suggestion will be helpful

```
anikettiwari@12345:~/my_folder/project$ rvm list
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.5.3
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
=* ruby-2.5.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.1 [ x86_64 ]


anikettiwari@12345:~/my_folder/discourse$ rvm gemset list
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.5.3
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.

gemsets for ruby-2.5.3 (found in /home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3)
=> (default)
   discourse_project
   global
   rails5-portal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding **cd .** in the end of the bashrc file it worked.